# VBA Execution of SQL Stored Procedure Fails with adDecimal Datatype

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, stored-procedures

I would appreciate any help on this problem that has me stumped:
  I am attempting to execute a SQL Server 2008 stored procedure from Access 365 VBA and keep faulting out with "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors".
  This fault began when I changed a column in the target table from int datatype to decimal(3,1). (I now need to be able to store a single digit to the right of the decimal).

For troubleshooting/ testing, I stripped the stored procedure down to update this column only. (OCR_Freq is the update column, OcrxId is the record id).

I have verified/tried:
    1) The table column is set to decimal(3,1).
    2) The data type in the stored procedure variable is decimal(3,1).
    3) The stored procedure executes without issue from SQL Server 
       Management Studio.
    4) Changing the column datatype to decimal(18,4) had no effect.
    4) The vba code below executes without issue if the DataType is 
       adInteger.
    5) I use this code to execute a number of other stored procedures 
       without issue.

```
'VBA CODE:
Dim Comm As ADODB.Command
Dim lngRecordsAffected As Long
Dim param1 As New ADODB.Parameter
Dim param2 As New ADODB.Parameter
'************************************************
Dim ocrxid As Long
Dim OCR_Freq As Variant
Dim x As Single

'testing the formatting
x = 7.2 'doesn't work
'OCR_Freq = Round(x, 1) 'doesn't work
'OCR_Freq = CDec(x) 'doesn't work
'OCR_Freq = Round(OCR_Freq, 1) 'doesn't work
OCR_Freq = CDec(Format(x, "00.0")) 'doesn't work

'connection stuff
If con.State = adStateClosed Then
    con.ConnectionString = conConnection
    con.Open
End If

Set Comm = New ADODB.Command
With Comm
    .ActiveConnection = con
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "up_EOCR_TEST"

    '--- ADD PARAMETERS --------------------------------
    'OCR_Freq decimal(3,1)
    Set param1 = Comm.CreateParameter("@OCR_Freq", adDecimal, 
        adParamInput, , OCR_Freq)
    Comm.Parameters.Append param1
    'test record id
    Set param2 = Comm.CreateParameter("@OcrxId", adInteger, 
        adParamInput, , 8053)
    Comm.Parameters.Append param2

    .Execute lngRecordsAffected
End With
'END VBA CODE

//SQL Stored Procedure:
@OCR_Freq decimal(3,1) = null, 
@OcrxId int = null
as
begin
  UPDATE dbo.OCRX SET OCR_Freq=@OCR_Freq  WHERE OCR_ID=@OcrxId;
END
```

The error I am getting is "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors"
The above leads me to conclude that I am not properly "preparing" the value in vba for the stored procedure execution- adDecimal is not happy with my variable...
but I am at loss as how to move forward. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error might be related to the value you are passing (8053). The actual parameter type of `decimal(3,1)` has a max value of 99.9.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Param2 is the record id and that does function without issue. The issue is definitely with param1/ OCR_Freq variable.

Comment: Which OLEDB provider are you using (version)? Old version of OLEDB drivers can have issues with decimals.

Comment: The connection string I am using is: ODBC;DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=serverName;DATABASE=dbaseName;Trusted_Connection=Yes

Comment: I tried changing the driver from SQL Server to SQL Server Native Client 10.0 with no luck either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the solution was staring me in the face- I forgot to set the NumericScale and precision on param1 before appending it:

```
'VBA CODE CORRECTED:
Dim Comm As ADODB.Command
Dim lngRecordsAffected As Long
Dim param1 As New ADODB.Parameter
Dim param2 As New ADODB.Parameter
'************************************************
Dim ocrxid As Long
Dim OCR_Freq As Variant
Dim x As Single

'testing the formatting
x = 7.5
OCR_Freq = x

'connection stuff
If con.State = adStateClosed Then
    con.ConnectionString = conConnection
    con.Open
End If

Set Comm = New ADODB.Command
With Comm
    .ActiveConnection = con
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "up_EOCR_TEST"

    '--- ADD PARAMETERS ---------------------------------------------------
    'OCR_Freq decimal(3,1)
    Set param1 = Comm.CreateParameter("@OCR_Freq", adDecimal, adParamInput, , 
OCR_Freq)
    param1.NumericScale = 1
    param1.Precision = 3
    Comm.Parameters.Append param1

    Set param2 = Comm.CreateParameter("@OcrxId", adInteger, adParamInput, , 
8053)
    Comm.Parameters.Append param2

    .Execute lngRecordsAffected
End With
```

Comment: This worked for me. I was struggling all day long and could not find what went wrong. After reading this post, I eventually got to know that `decimal` type were the culprit